# nodemailer not working on either localhost or cloud?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

Iam tryin to use nodemailer to send mails using both my local system as well as on the heroku app but in both case iam getting timeout here is my code , now i have tried using both gmail as well as smtp email but still nothing works

```
exports.sendMail=function(req,res)
 {
     if(req.METHOD=="POST")
     {
         var email=req.body.email;
         var name=req.body.name;
         var phone=req.body.phone;
        var content=`
          <ul>
         <p>You have New Enquiry</p>
         <h3>Contact Details</h3>
         <ul>
         <li>Email:email</li>
         <li>Name:name</li>
         <li>Phone:phone</li>
         </ul>
        `;
        let transporter=nodemailer.createTransport({
            host:'chi-node30.websitehostserver.net ',
            port:465,
            secure:true,
            auth:
            {
                user:'chiragunplugged@chiragunplugged.com',
                pass:'foo123'
            },
             tls:{
               rejectUnauthorized:false
               }


        });
        let mailOptions={
            from:'<chiragunplugged@chiragunplugged.com',
            to:'atul.11192@gmail.com',
            subject:'Enquiry from datadock',
            text:'you have got enquiry',
            html:content


        };
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,(err,info)=>{
            if(err){

                res.render('final.ejs',{message:err});
                return console.log(err);

            }
            var success="message sent";
            res.render('final.ejs',{message:success});
        });

     }
 };
```

please go through the code and let me know what changes I can make to get this working.

Comment: It might be a good idea to not include passwords in your source.

Comment: @lix the account is for time being i will remove it later ,could help me out ?

Comment: Have you tried using 587 as the port for MSA Standard SMTP?

Comment: @lix yes but it is not working

Comment: Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: @lix connection timeout on cloud and connection reset on localhost

Comment: It's probably because your not actually running an SMTP server on either of these things

Comment: @lix can you guide me how to on windows 10 ?

Comment: If my answer has worked for you you can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely there your not actually running an SMTP server on either Heroku or from localhost, nodemailer does not do this for you. You can use googles free smtp server as detailed here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-google-s-smtp-server Which will transport your mail.

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 465,
        secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
        auth: {
            user: account.user, // generated ethereal user
            pass: account.pass // generated ethereal password
        }
    });
```

Change your transporter to the above and also provide gmail login details, then providing you have the same details inside your mail options it will show up from `chiragunplugged@chiragunplugged.com` as described in the options.

Answer (score 0):

In the localhost its not working because a secure and safetly connection is required for sending an email but using gmail[smtp(simple mail transfer protocol)] we can achieve it functionality.

Don't forget to first do the setting - [Allow less secure apps to access account](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps).

its given permission for access gmail account.

by default this **settings is off and you simply turn it on**. Now move on coding part.

//////////////////////----------------------------------------------------------------////////////////////////////////////

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
port: 587,
secure: false,
requireTLS: true,
auth: {
    user: 'your.gmail.account@gmail.com', // like : abc@gmail.com
    pass: 'your.gmailpassword'           // like : pass@123
}
});

let mailOptions = {
 from: 'your.gmail.account@gmail.com',
 to: 'receivers.email@domain.com',
 subject: 'Check Mail',
 text: 'Its working node mailer'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
  if (error) {
     return console.log(error.message);
  }
console.log('success');
});
```